# Angular pick up the wrong overloading method when create RTCPeerConnection.createOffer

Tags: angular, typescript, webrtc, overloading, typescript-typings

We have a webrtc implementation(audio/video) in our angular app. Works/worked fine for almost 2 years. Below are the library versions that we currently use.

- **Angular version** => 5.1.3
- **(webrtc-adapter) adapter.js** => 6.0.4(tried with latest 7.2.4) => https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter
- **(@types/webrtc) type definitions for webrtc** => 0.0.22 (tried with latest 0.0.25) https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webrtc

**Issue is:**
Now we need to give some `RTCOfferOptions` when we create an offer. When we give the options while `createOffer` it throws an error and stop compiling. Details are below.

**From**:

```
connection.createOffer()
    .then((offer) => /* implemntation for offer */)
    .catch((error) => /* implemntation for error */);
```

**To**:

```
protected offerOption: RTCOfferOptions = <RTCOfferOptions>{offerToReceiveAudio: 1, offerToReceiveVideo: 0};
connection.createOffer(offerOption)
    .then((offer) => /* implemntation for offer */)
    .catch((error) => /* implemntation for error */);
```

**Angular compiling Error**

```
Argument of type 'RTCOfferOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RTCSessionDescriptionCallback'.
  Type 'RTCOfferOptions' provides no match for the signature '(sdp: RTCSessionDescription): void'
```

There is a method overloading in the type definition of the `webrtc`. But why angular picked up the `bad one` when adds the `offerOption`?

```
interface RTCPeerConnection extends EventTarget {
...
createOffer(options?: RTCOfferOptions): Promise<RTCSessionDescriptionInit>; // good one
...
// Extension: https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#legacy-interface-extensions
// Deprecated!
createOffer(successCallback: RTCSessionDescriptionCallback, // bad one
   failureCallback: RTCPeerConnectionErrorCallback,
   options?: RTCOfferOptions): Promise<void>;
...
}
```

May be it's very specific to our angular configs(can provide more if it's needed), try to search and check anybody got similar issue was not that successful.

Comment: can you try `connection.createOffer<offerOption>(offerOption)` ?
`

Comment: No didnt work With the same error + new one `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1`

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your code is referencing a different `RTCOfferOptions` than the `RTCOfferOptions` referred to in angular's d.ts. The two files might be referring to two different interfaces, even though they have the same name.

If your `RTCOfferOptions` is incompatible with the `RTCOfferOptions` in angular's d.ts file, then the first overload will be skipped because it doesn't match.

Go ahead and inspect them with vscode, and see if they come from the same file. This might be a result of using `npm link`.